# can't get menuitem on android 4.1, it crashes

Tags: java, android, drawable

I have code, that gets Menu Item and changes icon color. on Android 8.1 it's working fine, but when I tested it on android 4.1.1, app crashes.

```
Drawable drawable = menuos.getItem(1).getIcon();
                    if(drawable != null) {
                        drawable.mutate();
                        drawable.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    }
```

Menuos:

```
Menu menuos = menu
```

It is located in onCreateOptionsMenu

Logcat:

```
07-28 11:20:15.794 3443-3443/com.developerfromjokela.edison E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.developerfromjokela.edison.MainActivity$5.onPageStarted(MainActivity.java:223)
        at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:318)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    menuos = menu;

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Comment: you should look at logcat for all the runtime errors. And you can add log here as well for visitors to understand the problem

Comment: Now it's there, any ideas what causes crash?

Comment: @RM_HTMLKoodaaja need full code **onCreateOptionsMenu** to check view is initialised or not

Comment: Now the question is you are getting NPE on some line in your code. Start looking first yourself

Comment: @Killer Line 223 goes to Drawable drawable = menuos.getItem(1).getIcon();

Comment: @RM_HTMLKoodaaja where have you initialized `menuos`? It remains null when you invoke this line : `Drawable drawable = menuos.getItem(1).getIcon();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @tahsinRupam I initialize it in onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Ok, where do you set color filter to your Drawable icon? Please share more detailed code. You may set it before `onCreateOptionMenu` is called.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the line that throws NPE:

```
Drawable drawable = menuos.getItem(1).getIcon();
```

then there are 2 options:  
`menuos` is null or `menuos.getItem(1)` is null

so do this before the above line:

```
Log.i("menuos_isnull", menuos == null);
if (menuos != null) {
    Log.i("Item1_isnull", menuos.getItem(1) == null);
}
```

and see what'rs printed.
This is debugging and you must use it more often.

Comment: Menuos is null, but on android 8.1 it's not null.

Comment: If this is the case then maybe it's a bug. Test it in API 17 if it's ok there then you got your min sdk

Comment: I'll try it and let you know how that ended up. First I'll try it on 5.1